# np.any() alternative if column is different than NaN or 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I want to check if a column in a Dataframe contains a different value than 0 or NaN.
Therefore I tried np.any() but it also returns true if only NaN and 0 are in the column.

```
np.any([0 , np.NaN, 0])
True
```

What it the best way to get an output like this: (type of the column is float64)

```
df = [0 , np.NaN, 18, 0]
True

df = [0, np.NaN, 0]
False
```

Thank you,
R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace missing values by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and check:

```
print (pd.Series([0 , np.NaN, 18, 0]).fillna(0).any())
True

print (pd.Series([0 , np.NaN, 0]).fillna(0).any())
False
```

Or remove them by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
print (pd.Series([0 , np.NaN, 18, 0]).dropna().any())
True

print (pd.Series([0 , np.NaN, 0]).dropna().any())
False
```

Numpy solution - removing missing values by indexing with [`numpy.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) and indexing:

```
def checkNaN_or_0(arr):
    m = ~np.isnan(arr)
    return np.any(np.array(arr)[m])

print (checkNaN_or_0([0, np.NaN, 18, 0]))
True

print (checkNaN_or_0([0, np.NaN, 0]))
False
```

Thanks @AGN Gazer for alternative working also with `np.inf` values:

```
def checkNaN_or_0(arr):
    m = np.isfinite(arr)
    return np.any(np.array(arr)[m])

print (checkNaN_or_0([0, np.NaN, 18, 0, np.inf]))
True

print (checkNaN_or_0([0, np.NaN, 0, np.inf]))
False
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of `~numpy.isnan()` I would use [`numpy.isfinite`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfinite.html) with the understanding that it is OK to drop infinite values as well.

Comment: @AGNGazer - Thank you, added to answer.

Comment: @AGNGazer - I was a bit surprised, but now understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

invert isin then sum

```
(~df['column name'].isin([0, np.nan])).sum() > 0
```

or

```
any(~df['column name'].isin([0, np.nan]))
```